# How do I use a "start" image I created to be used as a start button?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game and need help with the Start button. I don't want the standard "Start" button JavaScript creates. I want to use my own image that reads "Start", as the actual start button. This is the code I used:

In the script tags:

```
function theButton ()
    {           
                document.getElementById("button").src="images/button.png";

    }
```

In the body:

```
<button onclick="button"()"><img src="images/button.png"></button>
```

Although this did work, the image is just plastered on top of the standard gray button JavaScript creates. I figured a function would be necessary, but I am not quite sure how to get that to go along with it, or if it is needed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: "I don't want the standard "Start" button JavaScript creates"?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. You can use javascript to make the `img` (or any other element) behave like a button. You can use the css `background` property to overlay a button image for any element. You can use an existing library like Bootstrap or jQueryUI and customize the ones they provide for you. There are lots of tutorials on the interwebs -- search "css javascript custom button".

Answer (score 1):

Use this html:

```
<img src="images/button.png" onclick="start();" />
```

And the script:

```
function start() {
    // do something here
}
```